# InfoPath 2013 form not able to submit, gives an error

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When I submit the form, it works perfectly. However, when users are trying to submit, it worked once, but then it keeps giving an error "Not all rules were run. site is offline/not available Access denied"

This is annoying as it just started up today. Please advise.Ive given everyone edit level access, and its still giving this error. I have checked the server links, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Worked with an internal expert with Sharepoint. This error was due to the permissions I had placed. I manually created a new group called "testers" and gave them Edit level permissions, and this worked. If I took away "Edit item", it did not work. So I had to give users both "Add" and "Edit" item access for the infopath form to allow them to submit.